# Switch statment: Does every case must always have the break line?

Tags: switch-statement, sonarqube, case

I know it does but I'm wondering this because using **SonarQube** (Code Analizer) i read:

> When the execution is not explicitly terminated at the end of a switch case, it continues to execute the statements of the following case. **While this is sometimes intentional**, it often is a mistake which leads to unexpected behavior.

So.. I can't think a real scenario where you intentional do this. Any example guys?

Thanks for your time!

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

You would use this fall-through behavior in a situation where you wanted the same action for multiple cases, without writing the same (repeated) code for each of them.

```
switch (foo) {
    case 1: printf("just one\n");  /* matches 1 only */
            break;
    case 2: printf("a couple\n");  /* matches 2 only */
            break;
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5: printf("a few\n");     /* matches for 3, 4, 5 */
            break;
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9: printf("several\n");   /* matches for 6, 7, 8, 9 */
            break;
    default: printf("a lot\n");    /* matches anything else */
            break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.. i just wanted a real scenario. But now i got it! Sorry, too much coffee by now o_o